# When using fixtures/factories in automated tests, do I need to create the model and resource first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

Ah this may be such an embarrassing question but I'm new to factory girl.

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|

end
```

**spec/factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email "example@hotmail.com"
        password "password"
    end
end
```

**spec/password_resets_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "PasswordResets" do
    it "emails user when requesting a password rest" do
        user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    end
end
```

And yet this gives me:

```
uninitialized constant User
```

So do I need to define the User model first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely. FactoryGirl cannot create a record without the model.

Comment: Thanks! In my deference I though factory girl could sort of spoof database instances. I'm new to TDD and I thought that you write all of your tests before you start work on your app. Now I see you define all of your models, then write all of your tests, and then work on your app?

Comment: No, FactoryGirl basically just calls User.create(some_attributes). My workflow is 1. Models, 2. Factories, 3. Tests, 4. Implement the functionality using tests. Also don't try to write tests for your whole app at once. Work on one feature at a time.